# Add unmodified files to commit after new remote was added

Tags: git, github, ssh

So Ive changed the remote url of GIT repository in my server and now I'm trying to push some dir's to the new repository but I can't as there are no new changes..

I've tried few things and neither of them works.

```
git update-index --no-assume-unchanged app/
git add app/ -f
```

I expect whole `app` folder to be added to commit so I could push it to the github

Comment: Remember that Git stores *commits*, not files. Commits contain files, but you might think of this as a bit like containerized cargo ships. You can't open the container and fuss with it. The carrier only moves entire containers around. If you want to fuss with the contents of the container, you pull the ship into port and offload the container—and then you get *everything*, not just one file out f it.

Answer (score 1):

Changing a remote has nothing to do with your local changes and with what is committed or not.

After updating a remote (change an existing url to another, or add a remote), you should fetch it:

```
git fetch nameOfTheRemote
```

Then push your changes (I will assume here that you want to push the branch `master`):

```
git checkout theBranchYouWantToPush
git push nameOfTheRemote
```

If your directory `app/` was already committed (which seems to be the case, based on your "there are no new changes"), it will be pushed there.

Answer (score 1):

Semantically another remote is not a different subset of files, rather a - potentially - different set of commits. If you just want to sync the current master (for example) to the new remote (let's say called `newremote`), just say:

```
git push newremote master
```